# object is null, but app behaves like it's not

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

This is a simple Spring MVC app that should check if student is in the database. If so, app should load student.jsp page, if not it should redirect to addStudent.jsp.

I have this in my service layer:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

List studentList = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("indexNumber", indexNum))
    .list();

if(studentList.isEmpty())
    return null;
else {
    Student student = (Student)studentList.get(0);
    return student;
```

And this is my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postSearchStudent(@RequestParam(value = "indexNumber") String indexNumber,
                        @ModelAttribute("studentSearchAttribute") Student student) {

        logger.debug("Received request to search for a student");

        studentService.search(indexNumber);

        if (student.equals(null))
            return "redirect:/essays/main/student/add";
        else
            return "student";
    }
```

But it is not working properly - even when service returns null, app behaves like the student is in the database and loads student.jsp. Can anyone please explain why?

indexNumber is NOT id, just some unique field in Student class.

Comment: If `student` is `null`, `student.equals(null)` will throw a `NullPointerException`. Please show your full `@Controller` handler method.

Comment: '@SotiriosDelimanolis' here is my full @Controller method

Comment: where is student declared and set?  wouldn't you need something like `Student student = studentService.search(indexNumber);`

Comment: Be careful with using `equals` method to check if an object is `null`, but instead, use the operator `==`.

Comment: Hmm, given that I don't see the declaration of `student`, I can only assume it's an instance member, which means you have a stateful controller.  This is bad.

Comment: @Taylor It's a method parameter injected by Spring.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis well now I just feel dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're completely ignoring the value returned by your `studentService` by doing

```
studentService.search(indexNumber);
```

Your `student` variable is bound to an object that Spring creates and uses as an argument when invoking your method. That object will pretty much never be `null`. And since

```
student.equals(null);
```

will, if implemented correctly, never return `true`, your `else` is always executed.

I don't know what you wanted to do with your `student` Model attribute, but get the value returned by your service and use it

```
student = studentService(indexNumber);
if (student == null) {
   ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try **==** instead of **.equals** in the case of **null** checking

```
if (student==null)
    return "redirect:/essays/main/student/add";
else
    return "student";
```